# AWS s3 r studio

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How can I read a csv directly from Amazon s3 from r studio. I can't just use read_csv, If I put,

```
read_csv(url("s3a://abc/rerer.txt"))
```

I get

Error in url("s3a://abc/rerer.txt") : 
  URL scheme unsupported by this method

I don't want to first move the file locally. I tried using functions like get_bucket in AWS s3 library but thats not in human readable format

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the package `aws.s3` from the CloudyR project.

To install this package:

```
# stable version
install.packages("aws.s3", repos = c("cloudyr" = "http://cloudyr.github.io/drat"))

# on windows you may need:
install.packages("aws.s3", repos = c("cloudyr" = "http://cloudyr.github.io/drat"), INSTALL_opts = "--no-multiarch")
```

Once installed you can read the file in just like this:

```
library("aws.s3")
r = aws.s3::get_object(bucket = "bucket",object = "object.csv")
```

As @Thomas mentioned in a comment if you know the file type you can use the `read_using()` function in combination with `fread` or `read_csv` or whatever R function you normally use. This saves a parsing step after you've retrieved the datum.

If your credentials are already environment variables, almost no setup is required. Otherwise, you can add them like this:

```
Sys.setenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" = "mykey",
           "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" = "mysecretkey",
           "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" = "us-east-1",
           "AWS_SESSION_TOKEN" = "mytoken")
```

There's also support for multiple AWS accounts. You can find the CloudyR project and its docs here:

https://github.com/cloudyr

Specifically, the AWS S3 API Client pages of CloudyR are found here:

https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.s3

Comment: Thank you for your response. I got that to work. The problem is that you can't use the variable r. It's not in human readable format. Like I want a variable, which would be the equivalent of read_csv(file) when file is local for a file in S3.

Comment: If you know the object is a csv, you can try using `aws.s3::read_using()` rather than `get_object()` to read the content using whatever import function you would normally use for a csv.

Comment: @Ark I just logged back in and read both comments. Thanks Thomas for giving him that guidance, I will add that comment to my answer if you don't mind. I will cite you properly.